# TypeError: create_user() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'username' and 'email'

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I am trying to create a super user but i have been getting one error. This

```
TypeError: create_user() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'username' and 
'email'
```

here is my models.py file

```
class UserManager(BaseUserManager):
    def create_user(self, birth_date, fullname, country, username, email, password=None, **other_fields):
        if username is None:
            raise ValueError("users should have a username")
        if email is None:
            raise ValueError("users should have an email")
        # if birth_date is None:
        #     raise TypeError(
        #         "users must include their birth date for validation")

        user = self.model(birth_date=birth_date, fullname=fullname, country=country, username=username, email=self.normalize_email(
            email))
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user

    def create_superuser(self, username, email, password=None):
        if password is None:
            raise TypeError("Password should not be none")
        user = self.create_user( username, email, password)
        user.is_superuser = True
        user.is_staff = True
        user.is_active = True 
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user
```

I have been seeing a lot of questions similar to this but i still don't understand the answers given, some say add positional arguements, I don't quite understand.

Any form of help would be appreciated

Comment: They are _positional_ arguments. Python doesn't have a concept of words; `user = self.create_user( username, email, password)` is actually saying `user = self.create_user( value_for_birthdate, value_for_fullname, value_for_country)` purely because that's the order that it expects arguments to be in - you defined `create_user` to take arguments in that order

Comment: You also defined it in such a way that it's not possible to create a `User` unless you know all of these things (e.g. date of birth) when trying to create them

Comment: This will also apply to the super user?

Comment: It's got nothing to do with super users. This is fundamental to defining functions in Python, regardless of whether you're trying to make a webapp or program a robot

Comment: So in this case what do i do now?

Answer (score 0):

Its because you haven't used the arguments `birth_date, fullname, country`
while calling the function. While calling the function it takes  `birth_date, fullname, country` as `username, email, password`

Comment: Well, no it isn't just that at all. They're missing but also arguments are being passed out of order and relying on positional interpretation. This isn't really a helpful answer because passing those missing values alone will still be broken

Comment: I have added them initially i made them false but i was still getting an error

Comment: @Somto try changing the order of the arguments

Comment: Should i now add ```birth_date```, ```country``` and ```fullname``` to the create_super method? Becuase when i added it to the ```self.create_user``` method it returned an error

Comment: Changing the order alone won't fix it. You could pass them with names to qualify what argument is what, and the function will still throw an error without defaults

Comment: @JohanJomy it tells me non-positional arguments need to come first